# Keystroke to Duplicate Current Line in Toad

Tags: toad

How does one duplicate the current line in Toad's query editor? Such as to create a cloned line above or below the current line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good, old copy/paste is what I use.

But you, you may open TOAD's **Options**, navigate to key shortcuts and set the (within the "Editor" category) **Line duplicate** action's shortcut to any key combination you want (and which doesn't conflict with some other key combination).

[image]

Comment: Ya I Cut/paste too; and go way back. But I am having to Port a database and while learning what differences there are between 20+ reference similar textual *columns*, I am doing a process where I put the column name in the paste buffer, then need to copy the last  `Select ... union` line and replace the prevous requested column, Once the union line is duplicated, I execute the multi union query to see if it grows. Uggg... :-)